# Force http to https redirect across entire Angular app

Tags: angular, ssl, redirect, asp.net-web-api, https

I've got an `Angular (6)` app using `.net Web API` w/ Windows Authentication. Both are deployed to the same development web server, which has a valid SSL Certificate.

I'm trying to force an `http to https` redirect on all my pages. I've got the `Web API` side handled - all the `/api` paths to redirect to `https` via Kudvenkat's simple tutorial: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-enable-https.html

Create a **RequireHttpsAttribute.cs** class:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace api
{
    public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                    .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);
                actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent
                    ("<p>Use https instead of http</p>", Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(actionContext.Request.RequestUri);
                uriBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;

                uriBuilder.Port = 443;

                actionContext.Response.Headers.Location = uriBuilder.Uri;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs:**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

But as far as Angular routes (routes that don't look like `https://myurl.com/api`, but instead look like `https://myurl.com/index.html#`), I can't get these to redirect to `https`. Is it normal to have to specify `http to https` redirects both in the `Web API` code and in the `Angular` code?

If not, perhaps we need to configure our webserver to only use `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it by using a URL rewrite in web.config, like below:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

This should handle both WebApi and MVC/HTML/etc.